# How to access CSV file using OS module

Tags: python, csv, operating-system

How do I access a CSV file on my computer in Jupyter notebook using os module?

I've tried the below code:

```
    import os
    file = 
    (r"C:\Users\...", "r")
    text = file.read()
    file.close
```

Comment: You can use `file = open(r"C:\Users\...", "r")`, `os` is not needed here

Answer (score 1):

You can use it directly without os module:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test.csv","r") as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()
```

OR

```
f = open(r"C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test.csv", "r")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually open and close the file, the keyword 'with' does that for you:

```
import csv

file = r'path\to\your.csv'

with open(file, 'r') as csvfile:
    # do something
```

For more info please check the official documentation of the CSV module.